# $mdDialog could not load template with ngtemplates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material 1.1.1, AngularJS 1.5.8 and Grunt with grunt-angular-templates 0.5.7. After building my application my $mdDialog does not find the view. But I found it in my Template cache.

```
angular.module('app').controller("myController", ["$mdDialog", function($mdDialog) {
    $scope.showDialog = function() {
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: myModalController,
            templateUrl: '/views/directives/modal/myModal.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            clickOutsideToClose: true
        }).then(function() {
            //success action
        }, function() {
            //fail action
        });
    }

    var myModalController = function($scope, $mdDialog) {
        $scope.hide = function() {
            $mdDialog.hide();
        }
    };
}]);
```

What am I doing wrong? This is my Grunt task:

```
    ngtemplates: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                module: 'app',
                htmlmin: '<%= htmlmin.dist.options %>',
                usemin: 'scripts/scripts.js',
                prefix: '/'
            },
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
            src: 'views/**/*.html',
            dest: '.tmp/templateCache.js'
        }
    }
```

*Edit
I got this error:

```
vendor.f56bbb37.js:5 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: aProvider <- a
```

and this is what my cache looks like

```
angular.module("app").run(["$templateCache",function(a){
   a.put("/views/directives/modal/myModal.html",'<div>this is my modal</div>')
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I found a correct solution. The Problem was the dependency injection.

```
angular.module('app').controller("myController", ["$mdDialog", function($mdDialog) {
    $scope.showDialog = function() {
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: ['$scope', '$mdDialog', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
                $scope.hide = function() {
                    $mdDialog.hide();
                }
            }],
            templateUrl: '/views/directives/modal/myModal.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            clickOutsideToClose: true
        }).then(function() {
            //success action
        }, function() {
            //fail action
        });
    }
}]);
```

Google called the previous way as a "bad controller" and my build process expected a "good controller"

You could read about this here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Answer (score 0):

Add targetEvent like this, try it and let me know :

```
 angular.module('app').controller("myController", ["$mdDialog", function($mdDialog) {
    $scope.showDialog = function(ev) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: myModalController,
            templateUrl: '/views/directives/modal/myModal.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose: true
        }).then(function() {
            //success action
        }, function() {
            //fail action
        });
    }

    function myModalController($scope, $mdDialog) {
        $scope.hide = function() {
            $mdDialog.hide();
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: It should work now, i have made one small change can you please check again and let me know ?